# How does thermal motion tend to change the direction of electron spin?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrons, quantum-spin

Purcell(3rd edition, Chap-11, p-548) in context of paramagnetism writes

> Thermal agitation tends always to create a random distribution of
> spin axis directions.

I have trouble understanding how do molecular collisions change the direction of electron spin? 
My thought process: Assume that each molecule of a gas filled in a container contriubutes one upaired electron.
Now what's the direction of it's spin ? Well random , we don't know .
Now if we turn ON external magnetic field, then spin would align parallel to B (taking uncertainty principle into account).
Now, how exactly does thermal motion changes the direction of spin ? I understand that collisions can change the direction of axis of rotation(AOR) of molecules. So is direction of spin somehow related to the direction of AOR ? (seems unlikely).

Answer (score 1):

A clue is already hidden in your question. You understand that the spin is influenced by the external magnetic field. If you replace spin with magnetic dipole, the phenomenon of thermal disturbance of the alignment of the spins becomes much clearer.

The disturbance occurs because an electron is not only an electric charge, but also a magnetic dipole. To operate here with the spin only complicates the matter. The valence electrons are (as long as we are not talking about an ionised gas) bound with their magnetic moment to the total moment of the atom / molecule. In an external magnetic field, this total moment is rotated in the direction of the external field as well as the valence electrons themselves. However, the thermal collisions keep disturbing this alignment. The phenomenon occurs up to temperatures before the Bose-Einstein condensate.